# Unable to get a websocket app work through kubernetes ingress-nginx in a non-root context path

Tags: nginx, websocket, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Here is a sample WebSocket app that I'm trying to get it to work from a Kubernetes ingress-nginx controller.

Kubernetes yaml:

```
echo "
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wseg
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: websocketexample
        image: nicksardo/websocketexample
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: podname
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ws-example-svc
  labels:
    app: wseg
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: wseg
---

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ws-example-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ws-example-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /somecontext

" | kubectl create -f -
```

I get this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://myhostname.com/somecontext/ws?encoding=text' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

When I try to connect using a WebSocket client web page like this http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

The version of ingress-nginx is 0.14.0.  This version supports WebSockets.

---

Update, I'm able to directly access the websocket running pod, when I port-forward from my localhost to pod's port.

```
[rpalaniappan@sdgl15280a331:~/git/zalenium] $ kubectl get pods -l app=wseg
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ws-example-5dddb98cfb-vmdt5   1/1       Running   0          5h
[rpalaniappan@sdgl15280a331:~/git/zalenium] $ kubectl port-forward ws-example-5dddb98cfb-vmdt5 8080:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 8080
Handling connection for 8080
```

---

```
[rpalaniappan@sdgl15280a331:~/git/zalenium] $ wscat -c ws://localhost:8080/ws
connected (press CTRL+C to quit)
< Connected to ws-example-5dddb98cfb-vmdt5
> hi
< hi
< ws-example-5dddb98cfb-vmdt5 reports time: 2018-12-28 01:19:00.788098266 +0000 UTC
```

Comment: Because you said nginx-controller rather than ingress-nginx, are you using the community ingress-nginx or the Nginx Inc nginx-ingress-controller?

Comment: I'm using ingress-nginx the open source community one.

Comment: What path exposes the websocket in your container? `/ws`? `/`?

Comment: app listens on /ws; I want this app to be reached through ingress by this path:  ingress/somecontext/ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/miscellaneous/#websockets

> If the NGINX ingress controller is exposed with a service
>   type=LoadBalancer make sure the protocol between the loadbalancer and
>   NGINX is TCP.

Sample AWS L4 Service https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/deploy/provider/aws/service-l4.yaml#L11

```
# Enable PROXY protocol
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
```

Answer (score 4):

So basically this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

is stripping the `/ws` from the request (combined with `path: /ws`) that gets sent to the backend everytime your browser tries to issue a WebSocket connection request.  The backend expects `/ws` when it receives a connection request.

If you specify `path: /mypath` and `/mypath/*` it works (works for me):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ws-example-svc
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myhostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ws-example-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /mypath
      - backend:
          serviceName: ws-example-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /mypath/*
```

Comment: Thanks @Rico.  I actually want ingress-nginx to listen on non root.  I updated the question with a proper context root.

Comment: It listens on non-root already `/ws`.  The problem is that you also made the ingress listen on `/ws`.

Comment: Yes the app listens on non-root /ws.  I want the ingress to listen on on a non-root context (ingress/somecontext).   The app should be reachable through the ingress in this path: ingress/somecontext/ws

Comment: Thanks Rico for your answer.  Issue for me was I had set only http enabled as a proxy protocol (AWS L4 service annotation service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol).  After changing this value to "*", I'm able to get web sockets work